# Ansible Regex Search

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

I am trying to parse string from a list of sentences using regex search.

The list of sentences that I have:

```yaml
- my name is 'Andi', nice to meet you
- hello my name is 'Bella', hi!
- this is 'Cain'
```

The output that I want:

```yaml
- Andi
- Bella
- Cain
```

What I have tried:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    test: >-
       {{
         sentences | map("regex_search", "is '(.*)'", "\1") | flatten
       }}
  vars:
    sentences:
      - my name is 'Andi', nice to meet you
      - hello my name is 'Bella', hi!
      - this is 'Cain'
```

This is gives me what I want which is:

```yaml
- Andi
- Bella 
- Cain
```

My problem is when my data is like this:

```yaml
- my name is 'Andi', nice to meet you
- hello i am me!
- hello my name is 'Love', hi!
- this is 'Cain'
```

I expected it to show result like:

```yaml
- Andi
- Love
- Cain
```

But instead it skipped everything after the unmatched string and show results like this:

```yaml
- Andi
```

How to skip only the unmatched line instead of everything ?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the following `sentence.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    sentences:
      - my name is 'Andi', nice to meet you
      - hello i am me!
      - hello my name is 'Love', hi!
      - this is 'Cain'

    name_regex: "^.*is '(.*)'.*$"

    names: '{{ sentences | select("regex", name_regex) |  map("regex_replace", name_regex, "\g<1>") | flatten }}'

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: names
```

gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook sentence.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "names": [
        "Andi",
        "Love",
        "Cain"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```